# python post request error

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to generate authentication token from "belfrics.in" api

```
    import json
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    import requests

    belfrics_url1 = "https://india-exchange.belfrics.com:443/gateway/public/authenticate"
    belfrics_data1 = {'username': 'abc', 'password': 'xyz', 'stayLoggedIn': True}
    belfrics_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    belfrics_req1 = requests.post(belfrics_url1,params=belfrics_data1, headers=belfrics_headers)
    print(belfrics_req1.text)
```

Everytime I get this response

```
{"success":false,"missing_authenticators":[],"infos":[],"warnings":[],"errors":[{"JSON_DECODE_FAILED":["No error"]}],"results":{}}
```

I am not able to figure why I get JSON_DECODE_FAILED error.
I even tried encoding the params by using urlencode but still got the same error. I replaced

```
params=belfrics_data1
```

with

```
params=urlencode(belfrics_data1)
```

ok so I found the solution
by changing

```
params=belfrics_data1
```

to

```
json=belfrics_data1
```

Can someone explain why that worked?

The API documentation is here :https://india-exchange.belfrics.com/api#!/common.json/authenticate

Answer (score 0):

Your site expects JSON; by using the `json` parameter instead of the `params` parameter, `requests` encoded `belfries_data1` into JSON for you, making the site happy.